# Can not find the error (need numbers from a HTML tag)

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

For a webcrawler I try to read out certain object IDs in order to use them later in a new URL. Unfortunately my skills are limited here.

The html:

```
<ul id="resultListItems" class="is24-res-list is24-res-gallery result-list border-top">
    <li class="result-list__top-banner background align-center desk-hide lap-hide">...</li>
    <li class="result-list__listing result-list__listing--xl" data-id="104344246">...</li>
    <li class="align-center background">...</li>
    <li class="result-list__listing " data-id="89231199">...</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

So i search for each "li" with a "data-id". Later I need to put the ID into the new URL.
In my example I have just inserted the [li class = "result-list__listing result-list__listing -xl"], but I also need the [li class = "result-list__listing"].

My code:

```
(...)
def get_data(url):
    try:
        url = uReq(url)
    except:
        print("Fehler 1")
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")

        for biglist in soup.find_all("ul", {"id":"resultListItems"}):
            try:
                for lists in biglist:
                    try:
                        big = lists.find_all("li", {"class":"result-list__listing result-list__listing--xl"})
                        print(big.get("data-id"))
                    except:
                        print("Fehler 2")
            except:
                print("Fehler 3")
    except:
        print("Fehler 4")
(...)
```

In result I get many "Fehler 2" errors. Please help me find the easiest way to find all IDs. You might also be able to add a check to see if it really is a number. I have tried something with "isdigit", unfortunately without success.

EDIT:

Now I changed code a bit. Unfortunately I need only each code from "li" into a specific "ul". But here I get even only the first result. Why?

```
def get_data(url):
try:
    url = uReq(url)
except:
    print("Fehler 1")
try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")
    biglist = soup.find_all("ul", {"id":"resultListItems"})
    for i in range(0,len(biglist)):
        ids = biglist[i].find_all("li", {"data-id": True})
        objektid = ids[0].get("data-id") if ids else ""
        print(objektid)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error {}".format(e))
```

Comment: Replace your except at "Fehler 2" with:
`except Exception as e:
    print("Erro {}".format(e))`
and put on what it says

Comment: Ok: Erro ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: So if I change find_alll to find I will get: Erro 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: as for checking if it is a number: 
`isinstance(<var>, (int, float, complex))` which will return true or false

Comment: At your edit, biglist has length 1, so will only 'loop' once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_data(url):
    try:
        url = uReq(url)
    except:
        print("Fehler 1")
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")

        for biglist in soup.find_all("li", {"class":"result-list__listing result-list__listing--xl"}):
            try:
                print(biglist.get("data-id"))
            except Exception as e:
                print("Erro {}".format(e))
    except:
        print("Fehler 4")
(...)
```

We were going too deep.
`soup.find_all(...)` is essentially an array of (...) so each `biglist` is in fact `<li class=....>`

EDIT:
Use the below to fullfil your original request of finding the `<ul>` and selecting specific  `<li>` tags based on class

```
def get_data(url):
    try:
        url = uReq(url)
    except:
        print("Fehler 1")
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")
        for biglist in soup.find_all("ul", {"id":"resultListItems"}):
            big = biglist.find("li", {"class":"result-list__listing result-list__listing--xl"})
            print(big.get("data-id"))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error {}".format(e))
```

EDIT 2:
This will find all `<li>` with a `data-id` attribute and print those that come from a `<ul>` with id="resultListItems"

```
def get_data(url):
    try:
        url = uReq(url)
    except:
        print("Fehler 1")
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")
        for biglist in soup.find_all("li", {"data-id": True}):
            if (biglist.parent.get("id") == "resultListItems"):
                print(biglist.get("data-id"))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error {}".format(e))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it now executes the script without a message. Neither errors nor the IDs.

Comment: Take out the if statement `if (lists.parent.id == "resultListItems"):` and see if that throws an error, or prints a value

Comment: Now it prints for each hit "None"

Comment: Sorry for my late response. It works a bit. Because of "find" (not "find_all" - that don't works) it founds only the first result. But I think I can use this and will try to write the whole script again and new.

Comment: I've found an even better way. 
If you want ALL `data-id`s collecting and printing do this:
`for biglist in soup.find_all("li", {"data-id": True}): print(biglist.get("data-id"))`